# devise + omniauth facebook : current_user nil after sign_in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, omniauth

We have registration and login via facebook using rails, devise, and omniauth. We're hosted on Heroku, running two web dynos.

*sometimes* login with facebook is failing.  The actual handshake between our app and facebook is fine. In fact, in the code below @user is an actual User model instance, the omniauth data Hash contains all of the data from FB, sign_in seems successful AND the current_user is set.

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.find_for_facebook(env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info, current_user)

    logger.info ">>>>>> OMNIAUTH FB BEGIN >>>>>>"
    logger.info env["omniauth.auth"].inspect
    logger.info "User is: #{@user.inspect}"

    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")

    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    res = sign_in(:user, @user)

    logger.info "Sign In Result: #{res.inspect}"
    logger.info "CURRENT_USER: #{current_user.inspect}"
    logger.info "<<<<<< OMNIAUTH FB END <<<<<<"

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json
    end
  end
end
```

The client-side does a redirect (different actions based on login context) to another URL on our site upon successful login. At that URL, we check for current_user... but current_user is returning nil.  If the login process is repeated a few times, eventually it works.

We're on

- Rails 3.2
- Devise 2.1.2
- Omniauth-facebook 1.4.0
- Ruby 1.9.3 p194

Comment: got a very similar problem (in mine the current_user is always nil). Some people suggest to turn of forgery protection, take a look here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#google

Comment: Please post your find_for_facebook definition from your User module.

Comment: This is a nice tutorial: http://sreeharikmarar.blogspot.com/2013/01/omniauth-devise-authentication-using.html

Comment: I have the same problem, after devise sign_in, the current_user is nil for a while. After few seconds the current_user is set? any advise on how to solve this issue

Answer (score -2):

I don't know whether this is really the solution to what you've described, but I wonder whether this:

> @user = User.find_for_facebook(env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info, current_user)

should read as this?

> @user = User.find_for_facebook(request.env["omniauth.auth"].extra.raw_info, current_user)

that's how mine is anyways. NOt really sure that would explain why your app is arbitrarily letting the user sign in however.